# Textual Minesweeper in Java

Tags: java, minesweeper

I have programmed a textual Minesweeper-Game in Java. For me it was much harder than I expected. I would be happy if you have tips how to improve the design!

[The program can be tested here](https://repl.it/@Dexter1997/Minesweeper)

Field.java

```
public class Field {
    private boolean explored;
    private boolean mined;
    private String modifiedAppearance;

    public Field(boolean mined) {
        explored = false;
        this.mined = mined;
        // This value can be used for displaying the field and is set by the
        // user of this class. If this value is not used by the user, the field
        // has a default appearance
        modifiedAppearance = null;
    }

    public void setAppearance(String appereance) {
        modifiedAppearance = appereance;
    }

    public String getAppearance() {
        if (modifiedAppearance == null) {
            if(explored) {
                if(mined) {
                    return "X";
                } else {
                    return "O";
                }
            } else {
                return "_";
            }
        } else {
            return modifiedAppearance;
        }
    }

    public boolean isExplored() {
        return explored;
    }

    public boolean isMined() {
        return mined;
    }

    public void explore() {
        this.explored = true;
    }
}
```

Pitch.java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pitch {
    private int maxLength;
    private Field[][] fields;
    private int minedFields;
    private int fieldsAllreadyExplored;
    // if a mined field is discovered the pitch is destroyed
    private boolean destroyed;

    // maxLength determines width and height of the pitch (fields x fields)
    // fields are mined with a chance of 1 / minedPossibility 
    public Pitch(int maxLength, int minedPossibility) {
        // maxLength can not be higher than 99 and not lower than 10
        if (maxLength > 99) {
            maxLength = 99;
            System.out.println("size set to 99 (maximum)");
        } else if (maxLength < 10) {
            maxLength = 10;
            System.out.println("size set to 10 (minimum)");
        }
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        // generate the pitch
        fields = new Field[maxLength][maxLength];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
                if (random.nextInt(minedPossibility) + 1 == minedPossibility) {
                    fields[i][j] = new Field(true);
                    minedFields++;
                } else {
                    fields[i][j] = new Field(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isCompletelyExplored() {
        return maxLength * maxLength - minedFields - fieldsAllreadyExplored
        == 0;
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed() {
        return destroyed;
    }

    // tells the user how to enter data
    public void displayUserInformation() {
        System.out.println("x: line number");
        System.out.println("y: column number\n");
    }

    // returns true if discovered field is mined
    public boolean explore(int x, int y) {
        fieldsAllreadyExplored++;
        fields[x][y].explore();

        if (fields[x][y].isMined()) {
            destroyed = true;
            return true;
        }

        int[][] neighborFields = getNearbyFields(x, y);

        // check how many neighbor fields are mined
        int numberOfMinedNeighborFields = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborFields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[neighborFields[i][0]][neighborFields[i][1]].isMined()) {
                numberOfMinedNeighborFields++;
            }
        }

        // set appearance and if no neighbor fields are mined discover them too
        if (numberOfMinedNeighborFields == 0) {
            fields[x][y].setAppearance("0");

            // discover neighbor fields
            for(int i = 0; i < neighborFields.length; i++) {
                if (!fields[neighborFields[i][0]][neighborFields[i][1]]
                .isExplored()) {
                    explore(neighborFields[i][0], neighborFields[i][1]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            fields[x][y].setAppearance(String.valueOf(
            numberOfMinedNeighborFields));
            System.out.print("");
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int[][] getNearbyFields(int x, int y) {
        // determine the coordinates of neighbor fields
        int[][] allCoordinates = new int [][] { {x-1, y-1}, {x-1, y}, 
        {x-1, y+1}, {x, y-1}, {x, y+1}, {x+1, y-1}, {x+1, y}, {x+1, y+1} };

        // check how many valid coordinates exist
        int numberOfValidCoordinates = 0;
        int[] indices = new int[8];
        int indicesIndex = 0; // i find it kind of funny
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if((allCoordinates[i][0] > -1 && allCoordinates[i][0] < 
            maxLength) && (allCoordinates[i][1] > -1 && allCoordinates[i][1] < 
            maxLength)) {
                numberOfValidCoordinates++;
                indices[indicesIndex] = i;
                indicesIndex++;
            }
        }

        // add the valid coordinates to a list and return it
        int[][] validCoordinates = new int[numberOfValidCoordinates][2];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValidCoordinates; i++) {
            validCoordinates[i] = allCoordinates[indices[i]];
        }
        return validCoordinates;
    }

    // asks the user which field he wants to explore
    public void getUserInput(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("x: ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
        System.out.print("y: ");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
        System.out.println();
        explore(x, y);
    }

    // displays all fields of the pitch with the indication of the coordinates
    public void display() {
        // display x coordinates
        System.out.print("     ");
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            if (i < 10) {
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        // display all lines
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            if (i < 10) {
                System.out.print(i + "    ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + "   ");
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
                System.out.print(fields[i][j].getAppearance() + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pitch pitch = new Pitch(10, 5);
        pitch.displayUserInformation();
        while (!pitch.isCompletelyExplored() && !pitch.isDestroyed()) {
            pitch.display();
            pitch.getUserInput(scanner);
        }

        // game over
        pitch.display();
        if(pitch.isCompletelyExplored()) {
            System.out.println("You have won the game!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You stepped on a mine");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the player mark/unmark mines?

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is not implemented.

Comment: How do you determine the number of bombs? I had 14?

Comment: How many bombs are in the pitch is decided randomly. About every eighth field is mined. In the main-method the pitch gets generated. There you can change the value.

Comment: Ah `public Pitch(int maxLength, int minedPossibility)`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is also possible now  to set a mark.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*

Comment: I am sorry, I will not repeat this. Is it okay to have the updated version on repl.it?

Comment: @DexterThorn Yes, see the point 4 in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips I think I can give about each class:

**Main.java**

Some minor remarks:

- You could think of adding some way to ask for a user to input the Pitch properties
- You can close the scanner using `try-with-resources`: [see try-with-resources documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

**Field.java**

Again some minor remarks

- You *could* remove the initialization in the constructor of `explored` and `modifiedAppearance`, because the default values of `boolean` and a reference type are `false` and `null`
- I would consider renaming `mined`, to me it looks like it means if a field has been explored or not, instead of containing a mine. Perhaps `hasMine/containsMine`?
- The `getAppearance` method also seems a bit wonky, say you accidently set the appearance from the outside as a number, on a field with a mine. It will create some problems :D

**Pitch.java**

- You added documentation above the constructor which is nice. You also added a comment on the first line about the constraints imposed on the constructor parameters, which is also nice. If you would now convert these to JavaDoc, users of the `Pitch` class could also benefit from this!
- Also in the constructor, you added a comment `generate the pitch`. Why not extract this block of code below it to a method :) e.g. `fields = generatePitch(maxLength, minedPossibility);`
- For the explore method, should you still allow all the things being executed when the pitch has been destroyed? (I know you exit from the outside, but say the `Pitch` class will be used somewhere else later on)
- About the same method, you seem to have a bug. Should I keep on mining the same field over and over, I will win the game nonetheless. The `fieldsAlreadyExplored` is always incremented.
- In the `getNearbyFields` method, you talk about a list of coordinates. Why not make it one? Add or reuse a class `Point` or `Coordinate`. Then create a real list, e.g. `List<Coordinate>`. With this, you could even use some Java 8 additions:

  ```
  List<Coordinate> validCoordinates = coordinates.stream()
      .filter(coordinate -> coordinate.x() > -1 && coordinate.x() < maxLength)
      .filter(coordinate -> coordinate.y() > -1 && coordinate.y() < maxLength)
      .collect(toList())
  ```

  or

  ```
  coordinates.removeIf(coordinate -> coordinate.x() < 0 ...);
  ```
- Finally, it is not really the responsibility of the `Pitch` class to handle user input, nor handle the displaying of itself. I'd take it out and move it to an other dedicated class.